# How to allow acces to a symbolic link in my ~/Sites/ for Apache under Mac OS X Lion 10.7.2

Tags: macos, mac, apache-http-server, symbolic-link

I need allow access to a sym-linked directory within ~/Sites from my Apache.
I Symlinked the directories like this

```
ln -s ~/path/to/the/source/directory/ ~/Sites/source-link-here
```

Now whenever I fire up a GET request I get a 403 reply

```
curl http://localhost/~username/source-link-here/
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /~username/source-link-here
on this server.</p>
...
```

How can I tell Apache to allow acces to the symlinked directory and how do I tell Apache
to allow this only for requests fired from localhost.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Best regards

robertj

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is [a blog post](http://mkelsey.com/2011/09/16/Mac-Apache-VirtualHosts-Symlinks/) I wrote when I was trying to figure out how to do exactly what you are trying to do.

1. Enable Web Sharing on the MAC by going to System Prefrences —> Sharing —> Check Enable Web Sharing
2. Edit your username.conf file located in /private/etc/apache2/users and add the “FollowSymLinks” directive:

   ```
   <Directory "/Users/yourUserName/Sites/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
3. Edit the /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf file and make sure the line under “# Virtual hosts” is not commented out, like so:

   ```
   Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
   ```
4. Edit the /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file and add:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>  
       <Directory /Users/yourUserName/Sites/MyWebSite.com>
           Options +FollowSymlinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
           AllowOverride All
       </Directory>
     DocumentRoot /Users/yourUserName/Sites/MyWebSite
     ServerName MyWebSite.local
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
5. Edit the /etc/hosts file and add this at the top:

   ```
   127.0.0.1 MyWebSite.local
   ```
6. Make a Symlink to link your Code directory to one in the Sites directory.

   ```
   ln -s ~/Code/MyWebSite ~/Sites/MyWebSite
   ```
7. Restart apache

Comment: Welcome to Super User! [It would be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link only for future reference.

Comment: I went from xampp zend environment to the default mac/apache setup and after a restart was dead in the water. Step 2 was key. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

In fact only the first 2 steps from Emjay's answer plus an apache restart are necessary, here is what worked for me:

1. Enable **Web Sharing** on the MAC by going to **System Prefrences** —> **Sharing** —> Check enabled **Web Sharing**
2. Edit your `username.conf` file located in `/private/etc/apache2/users` and add the *FollowSymLinks* directive:

   ```
   <Directory "/Users/yourUserName/Sites/">
       Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
       AllowOverride None
       Order allow,deny
       Allow from all
   </Directory>
   ```
3. check your apache config

   > sudo apachectl -t
4. restart apache

   > sudo apachectl restart

Now Apache will serve the symbolic links under your `Sites` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting `403 forbidden` error. What solved my problem is in `httpd-vhosts.conf`, I replaced the below config

```
<Location "/modulename">
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
</Location>
```

with

```
<Location "/modulename">
  Require all granted
</Location>
```

Did the same for all the Location tags. It solved the permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

`Options FollowSymLinks` in httpd.conf for appropriate container

1. Find DocumentRoot string in conf, remember it's value. Check content of `<Directory "docroot here">...</Directory>` section for Options string. If Options missing - add string `Options FollowSymLinks`, if exist but haven't FollowSymLinks - add this parameter in order to have smth like `Options Indexes FollowSymLinks`. Restart Apache after modifying config. Test result, write it here
2. Read Apache docs

Comment: Hi,

sorry - This answer doesnt help at all.

Comment: Did you tried **do** it? you disabled FollowSymLinks in Apache config, you must to enable at site or directory level in order to use  symlinked resources

Comment: and check permissions for files inside ~, presence of DirectoryIndex file after it: solve task sequentially, checking **all** possibilities

Comment: again - I am not able to make anything out of your comments.
I am a total newbee concerning Apache (apart from my googling for the last 6 hours)

I simply have no clue what the **appropriate** container is.

What would be really helpful is a concrete example how to configure httpd.conf and httpd-vhost.conf.

Comment: @robertj - This is the solution to your problem. You need to edit that file and modify it accordingly like @Lazy_Badger said. It should be located under `<Directory /usr/share/web>`. Note that afterwards, you need to restart apache using `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl restart`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's happening if:

- Your source folder are on an NTFS file system
- If you're using an already created folder, which has different permissions, probably from a previous owner or installation.

I sorted out this problem by creating a new folder on an ext4 file system and creating a symbolic link to `/var/www`.

Comment: How is this relevant to the OP using OSX?